# Tensorflow import errors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed Tensorflow 2.2.0 using pip install and have some issues when importing in Python 3.8.
The following errors occur and I was wondering how this issue could be solved:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/[name]/Downloads/AnomalyDetection/Paysim.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Try: `pip uninstall Tensorflow`  then `pip install Tensorflow==2.2.0`

Comment: I would also add that in order to install tensorflow, you must have the 64 bit version of python.

Comment: Unfortunately re-installing does not solve my issue. Do you have any other suggestions? 

And, yes I work with 64 bit version of python (pycharm).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749) of this issue on GitHub, there are apparently two solutions to this issue:

### First Solution:

Begin with the simpler solution, you can try to downgrade your `tensorflow` version to `2.0.0` like so. To install this version, you need to have at least `pip 20.1`:

```
# update pip first
pip install -U pip

# install tensorflow 2.0 
pip install tensorflow==2.0
```

### Second Solution:

If the first solution didn't work for your, then you can download and install the new C++ redistributable x86 and x64 packages from [here](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x86.exe) and [here](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe) respectively.

Comment: When trying to pip install according to your suggestion I get the following error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0 (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0

Is there another possible solution?

Comment: Update your `pip` version using `pip install -U pip`

Comment: Pip version is up-to-date!

Comment: What is your `pip` version? Also, have you tried the second solution?

Comment: Pip is 20.2b1 and C++ solution so far not possible since I work on a protected computer from work. Will try my personal computer tonight!